# Synchronous Gauge for a Schwarschild Background

Tags: gravity, black-holes, perturbation-theory

Consider solving Einstein's equations in the Schwarschild background

$$ds^2 = -f(r)dt^2 +\frac{dr^2}{f(r)} + r^2d\Omega^2\tag{1},$$

with $f(r) = 1 - \frac{2mG}{r}$.  A common choice of gauge is Regge-Wheeler gauge, as defined in "Gravitational Field of a Particle Falling in a Schwarschild Geometry Analyzed in Tensor Harmonics", by F. Zerilli. In this gauge, it can be shown that for the $l = 0$ perturbation,

$$h_{tt} = -\frac{2 c}{r},\qquad h_{rr} =  -\frac{2c}{r - 2 m}\tag{2},$$

for some constant $c$, which corresponds to a small change of the mass of the black hole.  This can be seen more simply if we work in Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates

$$ds^2 = -f(r)dv^2 + 2dv dr + r^2d\Omega^2\tag{3},$$

and choose the light cone gauge $h_{r \mu} = 0$.  Then the $l = 0$ perturbation is simply $h_{vv} = -\frac{2c}{r}$, which again, is just a change in mass of the black hole.

We could however, also choose to use the standard Schwarschild coordinates and work in synchronous gauge, with $h_{t \mu} = 0$.  However, this gauge obfuscates what a change in mass looks like.  If we adjust the mass by a small amount, both $g_{rr}$ and $g_{tt}$ must change.  However, this cannot be captured by a perturbation in synchronous gauge, because $h_{tt} = 0$ by definition.  I would expect changes in mass of a Schwarschild spacetime to be gauge invariant, so is there anyway to see this in synchronous gauge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Schwarzschild mass perturbation in synchronous gauge by starting from the mass perturbation in any other gauge, applying an arbitrary gauge transformation, and imposing the synchronous gauge condition.

Doing this (quickly, you should check for yourself) I get

$$ h = c\left(\frac{r}{r-2m} dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2\right)$$